# Data is not updated despite SQL Server stored procedure returns positive result

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am making a web store in ASP.NET with a SQL Server database. I'm currently working on a "edit users" part of control panel. I have list of all users and "edit" and "delete" buttons for each row of a list. When edit button is clicked I put mail of a clicked user in `Session["EditMail"]` and redirect to `edituser.aspx` where I load user's data in textboxes and his role in dropdown. In the bottom is "save changes" button. When button is clicked it activate this method:

```
protected void btnSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string name = txtName.Text;
        string surname = txtSurname.Text;
        string username = txtUsername.Text;
        string email = txtEmail.Text;
        string password = txtPassword.Text;
        string country = txtCountry.Text;
        string city = txtCity.Text;
        int postCode = Convert.ToInt32(txtPostCode.Text);
        string address = txtAddress.Text;

        int user_role = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListRole.SelectedItem.Value);

        WebShop moj_nalog1 = new WebShop();
        int izmena_korisnika = moj_nalog1.Izmena_Korisnika(name, surname, username, password,     mail, country, city, postCode, address, user_role);

        if (izmena_korisnika == 0)
        {
            Session["EditMail"] = email;
            Response.Redirect("edituser.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Visible = false;
            lblError.Text = "Error!";
            lblError.CssClass = "text-danger";
            lblError.Visible = true;
        }
}
```

This is Izmena_Korisnika (Edit user in english) method in WebShop.cs:

```
public int Izmena_Korisnika(string name, string surname, string username, string password, string email, string country, string city, int post_code, string address, int role_id)
{
        conn.ConnectionString = wqbConfig;
        int result;

        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comm.CommandText = "dbo.Korisnik_Izmeni";
        // kolekcija Parameters
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ime", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100,                   ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Current, name));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@prezime", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100,        ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Current, surname));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Current, username));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lozinka", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Current, password));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Current, email));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@drzava", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Current, country));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@grad", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Current, city));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@postanski_br", SqlDbType.Int, 5, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Current, post_code));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@adresa", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Current, address));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@uloga_korisnika_id", SqlDbType.Int, 4, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Current, role_id));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int, 4, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, true, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Current, null));

        conn.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        int Ret;

        Ret = (int)comm.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value;

        if (Ret == 0)
        {
            result = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            result = 1;
        }

        return result;
}
```

And this is the SQL Server stored procedure `dbo.Korisnik_Izmeni`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Korisnik_Izmeni
    @ime nvarchar(100),
    @prezime nvarchar(100),
    @username nvarchar(30),
    @lozinka nvarchar(255),
    @email nvarchar(50),
    @drzava nvarchar(100),
    @grad nvarchar(100),
    @postanski_br int,
    @adresa nvarchar(255),
    @uloga_korisnika_id int
AS
    SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 3000;

BEGIN TRY
    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 ime FROM Korisnici
               WHERE email = @email)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Korisnici 
        SET ime = @ime, 
            prezime = @prezime, 
            username = @username, 
            lozinka = @lozinka, 
            drzava = @drzava, 
            grad = @grad, 
            postanski_br = @postanski_br, 
            adresa = @adresa, 
            uloga_korisnika_id = @uloga_korisnika_id 
        WHERE email = @email

        RETURN 0;
    END
    RETURN -1;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    RETURN @@ERROR;
END CATCH
```

When I click the button data does not update. No error or exception is shown, lblError also does not become visible which means that izmena_korisnika in btnSaveChanges_Click is equal to 0. How is it then possible that data does not update

I have almost same code (minus dropdown for role) in `myaccount.aspx` page that is also for editing user's data. It works there but do not work in `edituser.aspx`.

Comment: Does it help if you close connection after reading the parameters?

Comment: Does the table Korisnici have any primary keys?  Update only works when the primary key exists.  Otherwise you need to use Insert.

Comment: "lblError also does not become visible" I see nowhere in the code that it should do so, there is only a redirect. Side note https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern so you can simplify to `UPDATE ... RETURN IIF(@@ROWCOUNT = 0, 0, 1);`

Comment: How do you know btw that it's not updated? Perhaps it doesn't reload the values on the editpage but does on another page? Did you actually verify that your procedure runs? You can for example add a logging table that gets populated from various places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both TSQL and .NET DO NOT use return values to indicate success or failure.  Use Exceptions in .NET and Errors (THROW/RAISERROR) in TSQL.

And even if the stored procedure returns a non-zero value on error, you should never rely on stored procedure return values to determine success or failure.  Instead throw errors, and determine success by the lack of an error. The risk that the client won't correctly interpret the return value is too high.

Using stored procedure return values to determine success or failure is an old pattern that predates TSQL TRY/CATCH, and was never recommended from client code.  So just THROW in the CATCH block or omit the TRY/CATCH entirely.

Comment: There is no particular reason why `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` shouldn't have worked, I think we need more debugging info here

Comment: I totally agree.  But the question should be moot with proper exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you starting to create a "mess" here.

Let's clean this up.

Try say like this:

```
    public int Izmena_Korisnika(string name, 
        string surname, 
        string username, 
        string password, 
        string email,
        string country,
        string city,
        int post_code, 
        string address, 
        int role_id)

    {
        int iResult = 0;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(wqbConfig)) {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("", conn))
            {
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comm.CommandText = "dbo.Korisnik_Izmeni";

                // kolekcija Parameters
                comm.Parameters.Add("@ime", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = name;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@prezime", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = surname;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = username;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@lozinka", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = password;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = email;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@drzava", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = country;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@grad", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = city;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@postanski_br", SqlDbType.Int).Value = post_code;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@adresa", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = address;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@uloga_korisnika_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = role_id;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                iResult = (int)comm.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value;
            }
        }

        return iResult;
    }
```